# how to install caffe within google colab

Tags: python

when I was trying to run the code:

```
!make all -j$(nproc)
```

I got this error:

> [Makefile:591: .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_deconv_layer.o] Error 1

Can anyone help please ?
or have the correct steps of caffe installation within google colab?
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.